# Regex for METAR

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a parser for METAR (coded weather for aviation). Working with a regex to achieve this.

```
EGJJ 240820Z 29009KT 1300 R26/P2000 FG TSRA VCFG BR FEW000 SCT001 BKN002 11/10 Q1016
```

(fictional unrealistic metar just for testing)

This is a typical METAR i need to parse. The part i'm stuck on is to parse the weather phenomena.
In this case I need to catch FG TSRA VCFG BR.

```
(?<intensity>VC|\+|\-)*(?<descriptor>MI|BC|PR|DR|BL|SH|TS|FZ)*(? 
<precipitation>DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP)*(?<obscuration>BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ)
```

This is my current REGEX, im catching FG, VCFG, BR. But NOT TSRA.
I can't understand why that part is not captured. Anyone with some tips?

Comment: It is because only the last alternation is mandatory and does not contain RA. Not sure if the logic will be correct, but if you add RA to the last alternation is will match https://regex101.com/r/rogSmu/1

Comment: Ok that semms logic, I understand why now. But I would like to keep the groups as is.. If I put a * after the last group everything matches. Is there any good way to make all groups optional? Can't figure it out..

Comment: Making all parts optional will match everything indeed. Maybe you can refactor the pattern a bit. What is the logic for all the possible matches? Currently the pattern would for example also match `---HZ` is that desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using named capture groups, I'm presuming you're also using a browser that supports positive lookbehinds. You can make your regex work making all groups optional and using a lookbehind for a space and a lookahead for a `+`,`-` or letter at the beginning and a lookahead for a space at the end:

```js
let s = 'EGJJ 240820Z 29009KT 1300 R26/P2000 FG TSRA VCFG BR FEW000 SCT001 BKN002 11/10 Q1016';
let r = /(?<=\s)(?=[A-Z+-])(?<intensity>VC|\+|\-)?(?<descriptor>MI|BC|PR|DR|BL|SH|TS|FZ)?(?<precipitation>DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP)?(?<obscuration>BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ)?(?=\s)/g;
let m = s.matchAll(r)

for (const match of m) { 
    console.log(`Found ${match[0]} start=${match.index} end=${match.index + match[0].length}.`);
}
```

If you're running a browser that doesn't support these extensions, you can use this regex, which matches a space at the beginning (which is skipped by using a capture group) and asserts a space at the end:

```js
let s = 'EGJJ 240820Z 29009KT 1300 R26/P2000 FG TSRA VCFG BR FEW000 SCT001 BKN002 11/10 Q1016';
let r = /\s((?=[A-Z+-])(VC|\+|\-)?(MI|BC|PR|DR|BL|SH|TS|FZ)?(DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP)?(BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ)?)(?=\s)/g;
let m = s.matchAll(r)

for (const match of m) { 
    console.log(`Found ${match[1]} start=${match.index+1} end=${match.index + match[1].length}.`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Very good solution! I will read up on lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: @Speedbrake88 no worries. It occurred to me during the night that this regex would match two spaces next to each other, I've edited it to prevent that occurring.